# Хочу сделать валидацию и отправку формы на чистом css+js, по получаю ошибки

Tags: javascript, css, валидация, форма

Есть форма отправки. 
Пытаюсь сделать валидацию и иммитацию отправки формы (со страницы не должно перебрасываться, а просто над кнопкой отправить выводится текст "отправка") с помощью чистого `js` не используя сторонних библиотек, но что-то пока совсем запутался. 
Что не так: [Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/uh0trpqo/5/)

1. валидация полей, кроме текстовой области отрабатывает не верно. При
   вводе первого символа в текстовых полях тут же появляется зеленая
   иконка, а не по окончанию ввода пользователем и проверки введенных
   данных.
2. функция submit не срабатывает вообще - почему?
3. после нажатия на кнопку перезагружается страница. Как это можно
   предотвратить и выводить в простом лейбле надпись отправлено?

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('form-control');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

  if (this.value != '') {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok").style.display = "none";
  }
});

var textarea = document.getElementById('form-control');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

  if (this.value != '') {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok").style.display = "none";
  }
});

document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(event) {
  if (whatever == true) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submitting").innerHTML = "Submitting...";
  }
};
```

```css
form input,
form textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #8e908f;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

form p {
  position: relative;
}

form p i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  display: none;
}

form p .fa-check-circle:before {
  color: green;
}

form input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown)+i {
  display: block;
}

form input:valid:not(:placeholder-shown)+i {
  display: block;
}

#screen-3 form input {
  height: 100px;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #bb9300;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #ffc300;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form name="sentMessage" id="form" action="#">
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></p>
  <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></p>
  <p><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></p>
  <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" id="form-control" rows="3"></textarea><i class="fas fa-check-circle" id="circle-ok"></i></p>
  <label id="submitting"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

Comment: а чтобы по окончанию ввода выходили галочки обрабатывай инпуты через blur вот так addEventListener('blur' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот к какому рабочему варианту пришел сам, может быть кому-либо пригодится тоже

```js
function InputName(value) {
  if (value != '') {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-1").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-1").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function InputEmail(value) {
  let email = value;
  if (email.length > 0 && (email.match(/.+?\@.+/g) || []).length !== 1) {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-2").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-2").style.display = "block";
  }
}

function InputPhone(value) {
  let regExp = /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/g;
  var phone = value.match(regExp);
  if (phone) {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-3").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-3").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Textarea(value) {
  if (value != '') {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-4").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle-ok-4").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function sendForm() {
  document.getElementById("sending").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

form input,
form textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #8e908f;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

form p {
  position: relative;
}

form p i.fas {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  display: none;
}

form p .fa-check-circle:before {
  color: green;
}

form textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

form input:focus,
form textarea:focus {
  outline-color: #ffc300;
}

form input {
  height: 50px;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #bb9300;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #ffc300;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

form ::placeholder {
  color: #8e908f;
}

#sending {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #8e908f;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="POST" name="f" id="form" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" oninput="InputName(this.value)"><i class="fas fa-check-circle" id="circle-ok-1"></i></p>
  <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" oninput="InputEmail(this.value)"><i class="fas fa-check-circle" id="circle-ok-2"></i></p>
  <p><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" oninput="InputPhone(this.value)"><i class="fas fa-check-circle" id="circle-ok-3"></i></p>
  <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" id="form-control" rows="3" oninput="Textarea(this.value)"></textarea><i class="fas fa-check-circle" id="circle-ok-4"></i></p>
  <label id="sending">Sending...</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" onclick="sendForm(); return false;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Убери условие

```
if (whatever == true) {
```

whatever - неопределенная переменная и она == undefined, а undefined == false, поэтому и через if ты не проходишь

Answer (score 0):

Лови валидацию на джаваскрипте :D :D :D :D :D :D :D :D :D

```js
// SELECTING ALL TEXT ELEMENTS
var username = document.forms['vform']['username'];
var email = document.forms['vform']['email'];
var password = document.forms['vform']['password'];
var password_confirm = document.forms['vform']['password_confirm'];
// SELECTING ALL ERROR DISPLAY ELEMENTS
var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
var email_error = document.getElementById('email_error');
var password_error = document.getElementById('password_error');
// SETTING ALL EVENT LISTENERS
username.addEventListener('blur', nameVerify, true);
email.addEventListener('blur', emailVerify, true);
password.addEventListener('blur', passwordVerify, true);
// validation function
function Validate() {
  // validate username
  if (username.value == "") {
    username.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
    username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate username
  if (username.value.length < 3) {
    username.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "Username must be at least 3 characters";
    username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate email
  if (email.value == "") {
    email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "red";
    email_error.textContent = "Email is required";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate password
  if (password.value == "") {
    password.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "red";
    password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    password_error.textContent = "Password is required";
    password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // check if the two passwords match
  if (password.value != password_confirm.value) {
    password.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "red";
    password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    password_error.innerHTML = "The two passwords do not match";
    return false;
  }
}
// event handler functions
function nameVerify() {
  if (username.value != "") {
   username.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   name_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
function emailVerify() {
  if (email.value != "") {
   email.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   email_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
function passwordVerify() {
  if (password.value != "") {
   password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   password_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
  if (password.value === password_confirm.value) {
   password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   password_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #D7FBFF;
}
form {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.textInput {
  border: none;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #6B7363;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
.textInput:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.btn {
  width: 98.6%;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form validation with JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <form method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="vform" >
    <div id="username_div">
      <label>Username</label> <br>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput">
      <div id="name_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="email_div">
      <label>Email</label> <br>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="textInput">
      <div id="email_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="password_div">
      <label>Password</label> <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="textInput">
    </div>
    <div id="pass_confirm_div">
       <label>Password confirm</label> <br>
       <input type="password" name="password_confirm" class="textInput">
       <div id="password_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn">
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ivanova к сожалению, это не то. Такиз примеров тысячи. Мне нужно, чтобы валидация срабатывала сразу по окончаю ввода в каждое из полей последовательно один за одним

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант валидации с помощью Regional Expression,можешь переделать под     твой код,а так же для правильной работы  в место метода test() использовать методы search() или match()`

```
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
const name= /(?=^.{3,20}$)^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g;
const surname = /(?=^.{4,20}$)^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g;
const email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
const pass = /^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){6,10}$/gm;

function getValue() {
    if (name.test(input[0].value) === false){
        alert('');
    }
    if (surname.test(input[1].value) === false){
        alert('')
    }
    if (email.test(input[2].value) === false){
        alert('');
    }
    if (pass.test(input[3].value) === false){
        alert('');
    }
}

input[4].addEventListener('click',getValue,false);
console.log(input[0].value,input[1].value,input[2].value,input[3].value);
```

`

Comment: проверка срабатывает после каждого набранного символа? А мне нужно по окончанию ввода в поле, т.е. при потере им фокуса

Comment: тут проверка сработает после нажатия на button или submit